Issue self-signed certificate baseb on cert in AWS ACM-PCA
How to create new certificate using AWS cli or boto3 or other packages is clear:
pca = self.session.client(
            service_name='acm-pca',
            region_name=os.environ['ENV_REGION']
        )

pca.issue_certificate(
            CertificateAuthorityArn=arn_of_aws_pca
            Csr=csr,  # obj of x509.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder
            SigningAlgorithm="some_alg",
            TemplateArn="arn:aws:acm-pca:::template/EndEntityCertificate_CSRPassthrough/V1",
            Validity={
                'Value': 123,
                'Type': 'DAYS'
            },
            IdempotencyToken='12345'
        )

And for each cert AWS will bill me. https://aws.amazon.com/private-ca/pricing/
But here is my question:
Is it possible to create self-signed based on AWS PCA, or Already issed certificate. Using bash/python/go/anything. The goal is to use final certificates for client to be connected to custom oVPN instance and reduce costs from AWS PCA.
There is a custom oVPN server which is configured to chain of root and subordinate certificate from AWS PCA.
Config:
ca ca.pem
cert cert.pem
key key.pem

Where:
ca.pem - is "Certificate chain" from Subordinate PCA
cert.pem - cert for server which is created by the same Subordinate ACM-PCA
If such issuing is not possible: could you point me into the documentation of ACM-PCA. It would be also treated as answer.
PS: I definetely miss some point, and would be glad to add them in a question if you point me out in comments.

To use a some root (or intermediate) certificate in the chain for your cert.pem with you need the private key of that root. Never worked with ACM-PCA, so I don't know whether you can get hold of that private key

@derpirscher that's a feature. ACM-PCA won't get you ability for download these private keys. As I Understood. But can't find clear confirmation in docs.

No that is not possible for 2 obvious reasons

SECURITY It would enable you to compromise the chain of trust. If you could use your trusted certificate to sign any other certificate, what can keep you from creating a certificate for any domain you desire? In your usecase (ie generating client certificates) you probably would only compromise your own security. But think about the general implications on security, if that was possible.

BUSINESS It would render ACM-PCA (or any other CA) more or less obsolete. If you could create your own globally trusted certificates, why would you still use a paid CA?


On a technical level there are two reasons, why this isn't possbible. To use a certificate XY for signing another certificate

you must have access to the private key  of that certificate XY
the certificate XY itself must allow to be used for signing another certificate.

Ie, as you don't have access to the private key of any of the certificates in the chain of trust of your cert.pem -- other then your final cert.pem itself -- you cannot use any of them to sign a certificate.
You may now be tempted to use your cert.pem -- of which you possess the private key key.pem -- to sign additional certificates. But that is not possible either, because the basicConstraints field of that cert.pem most certainly forbids this type of usage (because of the two reasons mentioned in the top of this post). And any official signing tool (like for instance openssl) won't allow you to use cert.pem for signing another certificate, even if you provide the matching private key. You may of course build your own version of openssl to bypass this restriction. But still, no offical browser/vpnclient/... will trust the final certificate.
Of course in your very own infrastructure of vpn clients and servers, you can create a configuration where you don't need a globally trusted CA at all. Just create a self signed root certificate, which is used to sign all other certificates and configure your components to trust this root certificate. And of course make sure, this root certificat is not compromised ...

Didn't know about basicConstraints field. Thanks for information.
